# How to check if multiple numbers are in a comma-separated string?

Tags: php, arrays, string, for-loop

I have code like this:

```
<?php  
$kecuali = "6,8,9";
for ($x = 0; $x < 15; $x++) {
  if ($x == $kecuali) {
    continue;
  }
  echo "The number is: $x <br>";
}
?>
```

and result like this

```
The number is: 0
The number is: 1
The number is: 2
The number is: 3
The number is: 4
The number is: 5
The number is: 7
The number is: 8
The number is: 9
The number is: 10
The number is: 11
The number is: 12
The number is: 13
The number is: 14
```

Why are numbers 8 and 9 still in the result, unlike number 6? How can I fix this so that all 3 of the numbers don't appear in the result?

Comment: `$kecuali` is a string buddy. Rather check as `in_array($x,explode(",",$kecuali))`. You can also cache the explode part.

Comment: wow, thx bro, u solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`==` should be avoided; it attempts to coerce the types before running the equivalence test. So `"6fjsdkjfds" == 6` happens to be true because the leading `"6"` is cast to a number before the comparison: `(int)"6fjsdkjfds" => 6`.

Always use `===` instead.

Now, this change breaks your code further and seems like a step in the wrong direction. But that's because using your set of numbers as an array and performing a lookup with `in_array` (or `array_key_exists` if you want O(1) lookup time using keys instead of values...) is the correct way to test membership, not scanning a string or using `==` or `===`.

Instead, try:

```
<?php

$skip = [6, 8, 9];

for ($i = 0; $i < 15; $i++) {
    if (in_array($i, $skip)) {
        continue;
    }

    echo "The number is: $i<br>";
}

?>
```

If `$skip` (or `$kecuali`) isn't data you have control over, you might need to parse it into an array with:

```
$skip = array_map("intval", explode(",", $kecuali));
```

before the above code.

If you have large arrays, consider improving the complexity to `O(n+m)` instead of `O(n*m)` with:

```
<?php

$skip = [6, 8, 9];
$skip = array_flip($skip);

for ($i = 0; $i < 15; $i++) {
    if (array_key_exists($i, $skip)) {
        continue;
    }

    echo "The number is: $i<br>";
}

?>
```